# Swift: Lots of errors in consecutive if statements

Tags: swift

I'm getting a ton of errors in this code that make absolutely no sense at all:

```
import UIKit

func remove(input: String) -> String {
    if countElements(input) > 1 && (input as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1) = " " {
        return remove(input.substringFromIndex(1))
    } else if (countElements(input) > 1) && " " = ((input as NSString).substringFromIndex(countElements(input) - 1)) {
        return remove(input.substringToIndex(countElements(input) - 1))
    } else {
        return input
    }
}

remove("hello")
```

The errors:

```
Line 6 - Expected ',' separator
Line 6 - Expected Expression in list of expressions
Line 10 - Expected '{' after 'if' condition
Line 11 - Expected ')' in expression list
Line 13 - Ambiguous use of 'remove'
```

These errors make no sense at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is line 6 the one that starts with the first `else if`?

Comment: Yes, line 6 is the only one that starts with 'else if'.

Comment: Most c-like languages require you to put parentheses around the conditional expression, which you did not do in your first `if`.

Comment: In most, yes, but you are not required to do this in Swift. In my first version of this code I did do that, but then I thought I was getting these errors for putting parentheses when they were not needed (I know an unlikely solution but nevertheless I persisted). I got the same errors as before, no different.

Answer (score 2):

```
(input as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1) = " "
```

This is an incomplete expression and incorrect use of the equality operator.

```
(input as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)) == " " 
                                                                      ^  ^
```

I added a `)` to complete the call to `substringWithRange` and another `=` to test for equality as apposed to assignment.

This misuse of the equality vs assignment operator also happens in the `else if`.

Comment: Thank you - Fixed four of the errors, but two more have arrived, and the last one (the one on line 13) is also still there.      ____

Line 5: Cannot invoke 'remove' with an argument of type 'String'___
Line 7: Cannot invoke 'remove' with an argument of type 'String'.  
Does recursion not work in Swift? Or am I not calling my functions correctly?

Comment: I also made the changes on the 'else if' line when I got the errors above.

Comment: You function's name `remove` is colliding with an existing function. I would recommend renaming it.